# ArcMap toolbox failed to generate results for some users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, buffer

Recently an odd problem with ArcMap happened in our office. Many people could not run the Toolbox properly. The usual map displaying was fine. But when using the Toolbox, even just a tiny job such as buffering a simple polygon, it generated no output. The Results window told that the software was running (a symbol of a hourglass under the Current Session), but it ran for a long time without any output.

Curiously, when I logged in as the administrator, it worked fine. Even when I created a new account as a standard user, the Toolbox worked. It seemed just the main user of that computer could not run the tools properly.

The data were from the local drive. We used ArcGIS 10.2.2. The system included both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: When it's slow or appears not to work make sure that the user is not reading/writing to a shared drive.  Please provide more description of the data being buffered, its coordinate system and the parameter values being used.

Comment: Thank you, @PolyGeo. The data were from the local drive, not a shared one. We tried different coordinate systems, including WGS84 and TM97. The issues was, for the same operation, it was only problematic for certain users.

Comment: Sounds like a Normal.MXT template issue.

Comment: Thank you, @Vince. But it didn't help.

Comment: The fact that it works with a new user means the old user's profile is somehow corrupted.  10.2 has been retired for nearly 17 months, or this would be an issue for Tech Support. As it stands there isn't really anything we can do, either.